# How to render only the child component on parent data change?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, reactive-programming, meteor-react

I'm using Meteor with React to build a simple classified platform for my sample app. While working on the filtered search I've run into a simple issue.

I have a component that returns the search results after fetching from the DB.
There is another component (Search) that holds the form and passes props to the child component (i.e. SearchResults).

Here is the code.

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchResults from './searchresults.jsx';

const Search = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return {name: undefined, brand: undefined, model: undefined, type: undefined};
  },

  handleSubmit(){
    var name = this.refs.name.value;
    var brand = this.refs.brand.value;
    var model = this.refs.model.value;
    var type = this.refs.type.value;
    this.setState({name: name, brand: brand, model: model, type: type});
    },

  render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" ref="name" placeholder="Name"/>
            <input type="text" ref="brand" placeholder="Brand"/>
            <input type="text" ref="model" placeholder="Model"/>
            <input type="text" ref="type" placeholder="Type"/>
            <button type="submit" action="submit">Submit Form</button>
          </form>
          <SearchResults name={this.state.name} model={this.state.model} brand={this.state.brand} type={this.state.type} />
        </div>
      );
}
});

export default Search;
```

What's happening is, as I submit the form the search result is returned as it's supposed to, but as the name and other fields are as a state of the parent component when the state is changed the complete component re-renders including the parent and the child component. Which is the way it is supposed to happen.

I'd like to know if there is any other way to do it.

I want to re-render just my child component on a data change in my parent component.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible, if you short-circuit the rerendering in the parent it will also prevent the child from rerendering. Read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html) and [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html)

Comment: Agreed. That's how it is supposed to work. Is there any other way to solve the issue? I only want the child component to re-render on data change in the parent.

Comment: @nishant-arora, Wrap the child at another component and handle this in it

Comment: But I think it is premature optimization. Trying to silence the state you just confuse the application for the dubious benefits. It really is a bottleneck in your application?
Simplicity of the React useful for debugging. And virtual dom helps save performance  even with multiple renders.

Comment: Theoretically, you could always return false from `shouldComponentUpdate` in the parent,store the data directly in `this.data = data` and pass this object down to the child, that way they will share the same data object. But with such config the child's update's lifecycle methods will never get called hence it will have to call `forceUpdate` manually once the data changes and it needs to know when it changes. So the parent has to fire an event in that case to which the child needs to subscribe to, and as you can see this whole thing just adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Or you can separate Search and SearchResult, wrap them into parent component, which maintains state, and pass state to both children as props. Also have shouldComponentUpdate returning false on Search component (or whatever you don't want to update). And provide callback to Search, which will handle form submit and update state. This way parent, of course, will also be re-rendered, but as soon as it's a wrapper component, there is nothing to re-render, except children. (one of which returns false from shouldComponentUpdate). Will it do the trick for you?